What three things will be called by the name of The Holy One, Blessed Be He in the future era?
I remember learning this in a gemera in Sanhedrin. Is that right? What page can I find this on? Thanks

See Bava Basra 75b

@User123 thank you. I guess I just misremembered the mesechta I saw it in. You could use this to write an answer
